# ASPNETBOILERPLATE - MVC Bundle out of memory error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, aspnetboilerplate

I added the following method into MpaBundleConfig.cs file. I also added a similar method for the JS files.

```
        private static void EXLNTAddMpaCssLibs(BundleCollection bundles, bool isRTL)
    {
        bundles.Add(
            new StyleBundle("~/Bundles/Common/EXLNT/css" + (isRTL ? "RTL" : ""))
                .Include(StylePaths.Bootstrap_DatePicker)  
                .Include(StylePaths.Bootstrap_DateTimePicker) 
                .Include(StylePaths.Bootstrap_DataTables) 
                .Include(StylePaths.DataTables) 
                .Include(StylePaths.Select2) 
                .Include(StylePaths.Select2_Bootstrap) 
                .ForceOrdered()
            );
    }
```

Soon as I run the application, after login, I get the error:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

All I'm trying to do is add some JS/CSS files that I added into the solution, after getting my solution from ASPNETZERO download. Any ideas on how I can resolve this error?

Comment: Is there any stack trace?

Comment: here is stack trace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HAoiVVXzY7X2N4S21uWW44YTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Your stack trace shows that this exception is thrown by bundler/minifier library. Maybe one of the style files you added some css code which makes bundler failing. You can remove one by one to understand which one it is. This problem does not seems related to ABP or ASPNET ZERO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hikalkan - Thanks to your response, I looked a little closer at my issue and found the root cause. As I was doing the code merge to upgrade to V4.2, when I copied over from my existing code base, I mistakenly copied JS file paths in the "StylePaths.cs" files and CSS file paths into the "ScriptPaths.cs" file!!